# button click counter android

Tags: java, android

okay i am building an app that have 24 question and every question have 4 answers in 24 layout
and the button in the 24 layout have the same id and on click values and i am trying to to count the every button click in the 24 layout and the last layout show the result of every button clicked but in the last layout the app crash
here is the code i am using

```
package com.example.andoid.disctest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivityresult extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txtCount;
Button btnCount;
int count = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activityresult);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.d_result);


     btnCount.findViewById(R.id.button_d);

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count ++;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        }
    });


}

}
```

> 12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.andoid.disctest, PID: 13188
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andoid.disctest/com.example.andoid.disctest.MainActivity_result}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.andoid.disctest.MainActivity_result.onCreate(MainActivity_result.java:24)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>   12-27 20:56:54.169 13188-13188/com.example.andoid.disctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post the stack trace!

Answer (score 1):

`btnCount` is not initialized.
You should replace:

```
btnCount.findViewById(R.id.button_d);
```

with:

```
btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_d);
```

Comment: @polaalper 
The stacktrace shows that there is a problem starting `MainActivity_result`, but here you have posted code for `MainActivityresult`. So somewhere in your app you are referring to `MainActivity_result`, but it is wrong, OR the name of this class `MainActivityresult` is wrong.